# Need a Android Studio/OSMDroid Guide for a school project

Tags: android, gps, location, maps, osmdroid

I'm currently developping an App in a school/exam purpose.
I'm using Android Studio 2.0 and an OPO with 5.1.1 on it and a Nexus 7 with 6.0.1 !

The goal is to display the location of the device on a map, and to trace a route passing by waypoints (cultural buildings).

I have no problem displaying the map (I'm able to center it on my city and with a good zoom level)

Now I want to display the current location of the device.
I encounter problems with permissions..

My manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="alpha.testmap">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    // AUTORISATIONS
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My MainActivity.java:

```
package alpha.testmap;

 import android.Manifest;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.location.LocationListener;
 import android.location.LocationManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

 import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
 import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
 import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
 import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private LocationManager mLocMgr;



@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
//Can't find the class of this fonction --> REQUEST_LOCATION);
    }else {
        Location myLocation = LOCATION_SERVICE.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocaation(mGoogleApiClient);
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
 //Can't find the class of this fonction --> REQUEST_LOCATION);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

    //Adding zoom ability
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

    //Create a default point
    IMapController mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(16);
    GeoPoint ptStart = new GeoPoint(47.215576, -1.549089);
    mapController.setCenter(ptStart);
    GeoPoint ptTourLu = new GeoPoint(47.21545, -1.54624);
    //GPS
    mLocMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 100, (LocationListener) this);

}
```

}

Comment: What problem did you face with permissions? Please mention in detail. As a good rule in life whenever you explain your problem to someone, consider the other person like a baby who does not know anything. So put in an effort to make the other person understand.

Comment: I'm trying to get the location of my device.
When I'm testing if the permission are granted or not, the last parameter of the requestPermissions won't compile..

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
REQUEST_LOCATION);

Comment: check out the example osmdroid project. Your code is missing the important MyLocationOverlay, which puts an icon on the map for your location.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with permissions is due to changes brought to Android 6.0 that requires you to ask permission at runtime instead of requesting at install like before.

You can read more [here](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library), under the "Manifest" section.